# Need a way to count the execution time of a unix command within my python script

Tags: python, bash, sh

Well I have a python script to test a product (at work), which at certain points in the code runs some bash .sh scripts to test certain parts of the product.

One bash script runs a command to start ffplay with the test device connected to check how fast it responds and actually starts recording.

How can i measure the time from the point the `subprocess.Popen('bash test.sh', shell=True)` (which contains the gnome-terminal command to run the test) starts, to the point when ffplay window opens and I can see the live streaming (about 2 to 3 secs).

I did search hard before reaching here but everything I found is related to using "time" before the terminal command to get real, user and sys time output, but this doesn't work for me and I expected something related to subprocess communicate or something else.

Any advice is much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What I did to measure time in a Python script was:

```
from datetime import datetime
def printnow(string):
dt = datetime.now()
print string, dt.second, dt.microseconds

# My set of actions

dt = datetime.now()
print string, dt.second, dt.microseconds
```

this prints the seconds and microseconds before and after the execution. You can also include the minutes, do the calculation of after - before and print that. But for me this was enough to find bottlenecks in my script.

Answer (score 0):

Importing the time module, and then creating a start a finish after the completion of your subprocess and returning the difference:

```
start = time.time()
if whatever_your_function_is_called) == True:
  finish = time.time()
  print "time to complete task was: %s" % (finish - start)
```

...is a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

There's a module specifically for what you need, timeit (https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html):

```
$ python -m timeit '"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 40.3 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit '"-".join([str(n) for n in range(100)])'
10000 loops, best of 3: 33.4 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit '"-".join(map(str, range(100)))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.2 usec per loop
```